# wpa_supplicant gives rfkill errors upon connection?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have not used wpa_supplicant before, so am confused as to whether a valid connection is being made. I used wpa_passphrase to get a psk and made that output my wpa_supplicant.conf. I then connect with:

```
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and this is the output:

```
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
wlan0: Trying to associate with e8:04:62:23:57:d0 (SSID='Guest' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with e8:04:62:23:57:d0
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with e8:04:62:23:57:d0 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to e8:04:62:23:57:d0 completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
```

It seems to connect but there are errors at the start, what do they mean? Do they affect the connection or does this look like I am connected correctly? I ask this as I try to give wlan0 an address with dhcp pr udhcpc and it does not get one, any idea why?

I have tried these two wpa_supplicant.conf's

```
network={
        ssid="Guest"
        #psk="xxxxxxxx"
        psk=<numbers>
}
```

and

```
update_config=1
network={
        ssid="Guest"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
        psk=<numbers>
        }
```

Both give the same thing

Comment: Try with `sudo` or as `root`

Comment: Hi Miline it's a root shell.

Comment: Can you paste your `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: Does your system have `/dev/rfkill`? Does your kernel have RFKILL enabled?

Comment: @Miline I pasted them above now, I dont see any reference to rfkill which might be why I get the error, but would it affect my connection if I dont have it?

Comment: rfkill is a tool to switch of the radio. Not it wont affect you. But your kernel probably does not have rfkill enabled. Can you see `/dev/rfkill`?

Comment: @Miline Nope it's not there

Comment: That is why you get this rfkill errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22090/discussion-between-miline-and-paul).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two errors of `rfkill` are by Rfkill, a tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices. Most of the time the kernel does not have rfkill enabled in it. And so there is no `/dev/rfkill` file present, and rfkill command will give errors like `rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device`

Control device here means `/dev/rfkill`

Comment: How can you get around this problem? Is there an alternative solution that doesn't require using Rfkill?

Comment: Which problem? Enabling/Disabling rfkill or?

Comment: I guess my question is this: Are the rfkill errors preventing successful connection?

Comment: I don't think so. Its just that rfkill interface might not be available if rfkill is not available.